# Obtaining source code of dynamically generated java classes

Tags: java, classloader, decompiling, javassist

I am dynamically generating new classes (using Javassist) and I would like to be able to obtain the source code of such generated classes.

Is there a library for programmatically decompiling byte code?. Note that the byte code I want to decompile does not exist in the file system, only in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to decompile (i.e. get the original source), save the CtClass into a class file on disk, and then use a decompiler such as [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui).

```
ClassFile cf = someCtClass.getClassFile();
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:/somefilename.class");
cf.write(os);
os.close();
```

Than just open up `C:/somefilename.class` in the decompiler.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I really would prefer to do it in memory if that is possible. I will try what you wrote if I cannot find something easier.

Comment: Unless you make your own decompiler or copy the source of an existing one and modify it to read from memory, then it basically has to be done like this.

Comment: I have been trying to find a decompiler that provides an all-in-memory API, without no luck at the moment. Inspecting the sources of JD, it seems to me that it makes a call to a native library sending as a parameter the path of the class to decompile, no its byte code, so JD does not seem to be useful for in memory decompilation.

Comment: No it isn't particularly useful for in memory decompilation. As far as I know no such thing exists.

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback @jili, I really appreciated. I edited a bit the question trying to focus it in that part. Hope there is a way to do it.